# Stopping hover function with a click function

Tags: jquery

```
        $("#theDiv").hover(function(){
            $(this).animate( {top: "300px", left: "400px", width: "50px" , height: "50px" },"Fast")
        }); 

        $("#theDiv").click(function(){
            $(this).stop();
        });
```

Code as above. I tried to stop the hover function when I click it, but it doesn't work. Or is it not possible at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#theDiv").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).animate( {top: "300px", left: "400px", width: "50px" , height: "50px" },"Fast");
    },
    click: function() {
        $(this).off('mouseenter').stop(true);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9m5zy/)

Comment: I would suggest a variation of this answer, with a `setTimeout()` function to re-enable the mouseenter, allowing the user enough time to move their mouse away from the element and avoid re-triggering the hover.

Comment: The question is "how to stop the hover function", are you sure the OP would like it to start again after a set time ?

Comment: the only two things I'm sure of in life are death and taxes. I was just thinking that it would be nice to be able to renable the animation because an element sitting in the middle of the viewport might become a bit of an intrusion. I meant nothing more than that, sorry.

Comment: Maybe an element in the middle of the viewport is exactly what the OP would like :-)  -- Seriously though, it does'nt really say anything about it in the question, but if that is the wanted effect, it's easy to add.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#theDiv").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate( {
        top: "300px",
        left: "400px",
        width: "50px" ,
        height: "50px"
    } , "fast");
}).click(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false);
});
```

[.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: This won't work, the trigger will occur the second you move the mouse after clicking.